# Can two SFMC instance be connected to a single Sales cloud?

Tags: marketing-cloud, marketing-cloud-connect, multi-org

I have two SFMC instances as below,

1. SFMC Core tenant (with only 1 BU) -- Existing
2. SFMC Enterprise 2.0 -- NEW

So our SFMC Code tenant is connected to a Sales cloud instance via Marketing Cloud Connector.
I wish to connect the new SFMC instance [Enterprise 2.0] also to the same Sales cloud.

IS THIS TYPE OF configuration possible? 
(Tried to illustrate via diagram as below)
[image]

If, yes do you see any pro/cons!

Comment: A blog which explains this concept in detail, very helpful.... https://medium.com/salesforce-architects/implementing-marketing-cloud-with-multiple-salesforce-orgs-part-1-cf8637cf0985

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Marketing Cloud Connect is a managed package that you install once per Sales Cloud Org. It can connect to one SFMC tenant as a whole ("standard setup") or to several BUs in one SFMC tenant individually ("SFMC Multi-Org setup").
SFMC Multi-Org does not refer to "multiple SFMC tenants", but to "Multiple connected BUs in the same tenant".

So:
Your setup is not supported. MC Connect cannot be installed twice per Sales Cloud Org to connect to two separate SFMC tenants.

Comment: Finally! ... Thank you @Jonas Lamberty for sharing the above details and additionally explaining the concept of 'Multi-Org'... It not only helped me, might help others understand this tricky concept.

Answer (score 5):

Multi-Org is an Enterprise 2.0 account configuration.

Multi-org doesn’t support connections for a single business unit to multiple Sales or Service Cloud orgs, or business units of multiple Enterprise 2.0 accounts to the same org.

[image]

Source: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?gclid=Cj0KCQjwpNr4BRDYARIsAADIx9w0993fnV9gcJFmJ_vCl4RX0AxzKFLBvTLa7ex7BmtogTgLaihXD9gaAk8sEALw_wcB&id=mc_co_multi_org_account_and_user_configuration.htm&type=5&sfdcIFrameOrigin=null

Comment: Hi @zuzannamj thank you very much for sharing the above details. However, I am aware of above configuration, and I think I was NOT clear of my query. So have added a diagram of what I am trying to achieve! .... Hope I am clear on my question this time... `I want to connect 2 TENANTS (not just BUs) to a common Sales cloud Org`